# How to select column from multi table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I have two tables are **subscribe** and **favorite**.
`subscribe [id subscribeid  subscribeto     datetime]`
`favorite [id   wordid  userid  datetime]`
So, I want to show these actively in news feed that can separate in each loop, where from which table?
my code is look like this

```
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM favorite) UNION (SELECT * FROM subscribe) ORDER BY datetime DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($array['wordid']!=""){
        echo "This's favorite feed";
    }else{
        echo "This's subscribed feed";
    }
    //echo $array['wordid'];
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

In the condition of **if($array['wordid']!="")** I think it should work, but when in echo  in commented line it always has a values, I don't know why is that.

Please help or suggest, thanks.

Comment: First of all `UNION` doesn't allow `SELECT`s with different number of columns.

Comment: `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alias function to union the result set. Based on cate field you can determine the results from which table.

Use mysqli extension instead of mysql

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT id, 
subscribeid As common_id, 
subscribeto, 
datetime, 'subscribe' As cate
FROM subscribe
UNION
SELECT id, 
wordid As common_id, 
userid As subscribeto, 
datetime,
 'favorite' As cate
 FROM favorite";

$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($array['cate']!="subscribe"){
        echo "This's favorite feed";
    }else{
        echo "This's subscribed feed";
    }
    //echo $array['wordid'];
    echo "<hr />";
}
```